# Is there a memory management guide for c++ like the one apple has for objective c?

Tags: c++, memory-management

As part of the Mac OS X developer library, there is a [very good memory management guide for objective c](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). It not only describes what the various memory management functions (such as `retain`, `autorelease` and `dealloc`) do, but when to use each method.

For example, it has the following guidelines for releasing memory:

- You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own
- When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own
- You can take ownership of an object using retain
- You own any object you create

It then gives detailed information about these rules, eg

> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

By following these guidelines, it makes it easy for people using your code to know when they are expected to `retain` or `release` objects returned from methods and when it isn't necessary.

Also, the guide is obviously written by people with years of experience working with objective c. So in the vast majority of cases, following the memory management guidelines would produce better code than coming up memory management guidelines yourself.

---

Due to these advantages, I was wondering if there was a similar guide somewhere for c++. There are many ways you can pass or return an object to a method in c++:

- by reference
- by value
- by pointer
- by `boost::shared_ptr` (or other smart pointers)
- const variants of the above methods

I understand how they work, but I am constantly unsure of what method I should use. There are so many different pros and cons to each method that I find I am wasting too much time deciding what method to use, only to change it later on when I find I made the wrong choice.

If I had a memory management guide for c++ like the objective c guide, it would be a much simpler job. So is there one around, either on a website or published in a book? Also, is there a set of guidelines that most c++ developers follow?

Comment: I believe most of those rules for Objective C apply to C++, since they are conventional. And you can also use Boehm's garbage collector in C++.

Comment: The ownership rules are established by the smart pointers, mostly. There's a very comprehensive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026705/46642

Comment: You don't need any garbage collector in native c++. shared_ptr and unique_ptr will do the job. Linking Herb Sutter's blog post on garbagae collection in c++ http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/25/garbage-collection-synopsis-and-c/

Comment: You do sometimes need a GC in native C++. For instance, to write an interpreter for a GC-ed language (like Scheme). You may choose to use an existing one (like Boehm's) or re-invent your own.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That post gave a very good explanations of what each method does, but doesn't give guidelines for when to use them.  That is what I'm really after, and having a lot of trouble finding information on.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't want to use a garbage collector, the performance penalties aren't acceptable for me.

Comment: I'm not sure performance differs so much. When I measured, I found `GC_malloc` to be only 30% slower than `malloc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that for Objective C you are presented with a convention that is used in the standard library and that is also used practically in every program for that platform.

C++ instead is agnostic in respect to which policy you may want to use for your application and therefore there are no general rules you can follow. If you use smart pointers there are certain rules, if you use hierarchical ownership (like in Qt) there are other rules, if you use a garbage collected approach rules change again.

More or less like for hardware, problems are simpler in Apple approach because there is no variety. It's debatable if that variety is an important resource worth fighting the included complexity or just a pointless complication.