# References between two smart pointers

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

Reading this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5026705/245265) :

> QWeakPointer - Do you sense a reoccurring pattern? Just as
>   std::weak_ptr and boost::weak_ptr this is used in conjunction with
>   QSharedPointer when you need references between two smart pointers
>   that would otherwise cause your objects to never be deleted.

My question is - could anybody explain me such situation on a simple example, when two referencing smart pointers could cause non-deleted objects?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, neither of the `S` objects will ever be destroyed, because the object pointed to by `a` owns the object pointed to by `b`, and vice-versa.

```
struct S {
    std::shared_ptr<S> p;
};

void f()
{
    std::shared_ptr<S> a(new S());
    std::shared_ptr<S> b(new S());
    a->p = b;
    b->p = a;
}
```

`std::weak_ptr` is used to break reference cycles.  If object lifetime is known to extend beyond the lifetime of the non-owning pointer, raw pointers can be used as well.

The same principles apply to Qt's smart pointers, like `QWeakPointer`.