# Issue with function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm planning on using function pointers to implement different functions in a class.
However, I've run into a bit of trouble while trying to implement one such function.

The code is here:

```
std::vector<int> * (*create_vector)()
{
    std::vector<int> * vec_p = new std::vector<int>;
    return vec_p;
}
```

The errors are as follows:

```
3: [Error] expected primary-expression before '*' token
3: [Error] 'vec_p' was not declared in this scope
3: [Error] expected '}' before ';' token 
4: [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'return' 
5: [Error] expected declaration before '}' token
```

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about function pointers, or is it a different issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You need function, that returns a pointer or a function pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector<int> * (*create_vector)()` declares a pointer to a function. A pointer. Not a function. You cannot go on with the pointer and pretend it's a function and define its body. You need to declare the two separately:

```
std::vector<int> * create_vector()
{
    std::vector<int> * vec_p = new std::vector<int>;
    return vec_p;
}

std::vector<int> * (*pcreate_vector)() = create_vector;
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot declare a function and a function pointer at the same time.

Simply define your function:

```
std::vector<int>* create_vector()
{
    std::vector<int>* vec_p = new std::vector<int>;
    return vec_p;
}
```

Then, the best is to make a typedef (for code readability):

```
typedef std::vector<int>* (*create_vector_func)();
```

And now you can use it:

```
create_vector_func myFunc = &create_vector;
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions are implemented and function pointers can be pointed at functions. Function pointers themselves are not implemented.

Change to:

```
std::vector<int>* create_vector()
{
    std::vector<int> * vec_p = new std::vector<int>;
    return vec_p;
}
```

Then you can declare a function pointer to point at `create_vector()`. Managing function pointers can be simplified using a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<int>* (*func_t)();    // C++03
typedef decltype(&create_vector) func_t; // C++11

func_t f = create_vector;
auto f = create_vector; // C++11 option also.
```

Avoid dynamic allocation if possible as it introduces additional complexity making the code more error prone. In C++11, move semantics were introduced so the cost of returning by value in this case are significantly reduced as the `vector` named `vec_p` will be *moved* from (as it is expiring), not copied from. If you must dynamically allocate use a form of [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available).

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you define a function pointer. First define the function with the body you have and then assign it to a function pointer.