# using boost::scoped_ptr if possible

Tags: c++, boost

I have something like this in pagePtr.h

```
typedef int (*FunPtrType)(char* sz, unsigned int max_bytes, char* arg1,
char* arg2, char* arg3, char* arg4);
```

and a static function which creates a object

```
static pagePtr* CreatePage( FunPtrType Ptr2Fun)
{
    return new pagePtr(ptr2Fun);
}
```

would boost::scoped_ptr help me not worry abt deleting those created abject later. if yes how should I implement in this case. 
And what could be the other possible better options, if available, to delete those objects created.

Comment: You need `std::unique_ptr`. `boost::scoped_ptr` cannot be passed around.

Comment: You could use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr: std::unique_ptr<pagePtr> CreatePage(...)...

Comment: could you help me with how the implementation would look like in my case using std::unique_ptr?

Comment: What are the problems you have with the implementation using `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 5):

[`boost:scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) is not copyable so cannot be returned from `CreatePage()`. If C++11 is available `std::unique_ptr` could be used:

```
static std::unique_ptr<pagePtr> CreatePage( FunPtrType Ptr2Fun)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<pagePtr>(new pagePtr(ptr2Fun));
}
```

Is there a reason `pagePtr` is not copyable? If not and it is inexpensive to copy then return by value.

If `pagePtr` is non-copyable and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is not available then you could use [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) to remove the responsiblity from the caller for destructing the returned `pagePtr`. With the downside that using `shared_ptr` does not indicate sole ownership and pay the price for unrequired reference counting (see [What C++ Smart Pointer Implementations are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available) for more information and descriptions on the available smart pointers).

From the posted code, `pagePtr` appears to a wrapper around a function pointer so consider using [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html) instead, which is copyable, and remove `pagePtr` completely:

```
typedef boost::function<int(char* sz,
                            unsigned int max_bytes,
                            char* arg1,
                            char* arg2,
                            char* arg3,
                            char* arg4)> FunPtrType;
```

Comment: Actually, `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor; it's the move constructor that's called.

Answer (score 3):

The idiom for having a function that dynamically allocates an object and safely returns ownership to the caller is to return a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> create_foo()
{
  return std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo());
}
```

This tells the caller explicitly that they are getting ownership of the object and the object will be destroyed when their `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed (unless ownership is further passed elsewhere).

Applied to your example:

```
static std::unique_ptr<pagePtr> CreatePage( FunPtrType ptr2Fun)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<pagePtr>(new pagePtr(ptr2Fun));
}
```

As for why other pointers are not applicable:

- `boost::scoped_ptr` cannot pass ownership at all - it is the most restrictive of the smart pointers (pretty much equivalent to a `const std::unique_ptr`)
- `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated because it provides move semantics through copying
- `std::shared_ptr` would work but doesn't make much sense - the function certainly isn't going to be sharing ownership with the caller because the function is ending