# Initializing a data member array of object pointers to the correct size and null

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I have a simple C++ Node class which contains an array data member of pointers to the same type. This array is dynamically allocated and its pointers should default to null but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

```
class Node
{
private:
    Node *_nextNode[];
    string _data;
}

Node::Node( const string &p_data, const int &p_levels ): _data(p_data)
{
   //unsure how to initialize the '_nextNode[]' member so that the size of the array is of p_levels and they all default to null pointers 
}

class SkipList
{
    private:

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`std::vector<Node*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
Node::Node( const string &p_data, const int &p_levels ): 
    _data(p_data),
    _nextNode(p_levels)
{
```

this will initialise the elements of `_nextNode` to `nullptr`s.

Consider using a [smart pointer implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available) instead of `Node*` to manage the destruction of the `Node` instances for you.

---

If you have to use a `Node*` then you need a `Node**` to point to a list of `Node*`:

```
class Node
{
private:
    Node**_nextNode;
    string _data;
};

Node::Node( const string &p_data, const int &p_levels ): 
    _data(p_data),
    _nextNode(new Node*[p_levels]())
{                              //^^ value initialization.
```

allocates an array of `int*` containing `p_levels` elements and value initializes them (sets them to `NULL`). `Node` needs to know how many elements are stored in `_nextNode` so `p_levels` would require storing also. Destruction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _nextNodeElements; i++)
{
    delete _nextNode[i]; // delete NULL is safe, a no-op.
}
delete[] _nextNode;
```

Just to push you toward `std::vector` again: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> _nextNode;` wouldn't require a hand-written destructor, the default generated one would suffice.

Comment: If I had to do it via Node* how would I do it?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
_nextNode = new Node[pLevels];
memset ( _nextNode, 0, sizeof (_nextNode));
```

Is this what you want? Also you should declare `Node *_nextNode[]` as `Node *_nextNode`
And you will also have to include `<string.h>` for `memset`

Comment: Without the [] in the declaration when it comes to using it such as in this example I get errors.

Node *tempNode = _head; tempNode->_nextNode[0] == NULL;

Comment: `Node *_nextNode[]` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Node **_nextNode istead of Node *_nextNode[].

```
Node **_nextNode= new (NODE**)[ArraySize];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
 _nextNode = NULL;
```

}