# Check if a pointer is NULL after it's object is deleted in other pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple problem like this!

```
class1 *a = new class1();
class1 *b = a;

delete a;
a= NULL;
```

Now  I want to check if b is NULL (or is deleted) also, but b always point to where a point previously.
This is problematic when I want to use b, but a already deleted before!

```
if (b){
    //do something here
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some have suggested, using a shared pointer will make this easier.

If you want to do it the raw way, here is why `*b` still points to the original value of `a`

When you say `class1 *b=a` you are taking a *copy* of the pointer value of a. So regardless of what you do to `a` itself, `b` hangs on to this original value.

If you wanted it to change along with a, you would need to assign a reference to `a`, or a pointer to the `a` pointer

```
class1 **b = &a;
```

So now, think what happens when you dereference `b`, what value is that pointing to?

it will point to your original `class1 *`. So, once you set `a=NULL`, you now have a pointer `b` that points to the value of `a`, or NULL

Comment: I think this is better than the shared pointer, as it preserves the flow of the original code.  A shared pointer would alter the lifetime of the object to not match the original code.

Comment: this is true, though it requires more memory management than a shared pointer would require.

Comment: Yeah I think this approach work really well, but it will make the code look more Pointer-Way, a is already pointer, now b is a pointer of pointer ^^. Never try this before, but i think i will try to use it from now in some case! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to have `b` update automatically after `a` has been `NULL`d. The question code also illustrates why setting a pointer to `NULL` after it's object has been `delete`d is partial, at best, and that a non-`NULL` pointer does not guarantee that a pointer is pointing to a valid object.

Use a [`std::shared_ptr<class1>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead, as there is shared ownership of the pointed-to object:

```
std::shared_ptr<class1> a = std::make_shared<class1>();
std::shared_ptr<class1> b = a;
```

the dynamically allocated object will be destructed with both `a` and `b` go out of scope.

See [What C++ Smart Pointer Implementations are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available) for an overview of available smart pointers.

Comment: so it's true we must use smart pointer in this case! No other solution for naked pointer !

Comment: @greenpig83 Yes, it is true. That's probably why smart pointers are created.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use smart pointers at all. See solution below. Some cases call for ease of use of smart pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't `b` be `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @Lol4t0, guess so. Depends really if it is essential that it exists for the other function, but the code suggests that is not the case so you are right.