# Making an object belonging to a class depending on input parameters in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm trying to build an object which is of a type which depends on input parameters.  E.g. my object is called 'process' and at runtime an integer between 2 and 5 (inclusive) is entered and something a bit like this would happen:

```
if (input == 2) TwoJ   process;
if (input == 3) ThreeJ process;
if (input == 4) FourJ  process;
if (input == 5) FiveJ  process;
```

Obviously the above will not work because the object goes out of scope immediately.  Is there a way to implement this nicely?
Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [factory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method) that returns a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available) to a base `Process` class and whose implementation is determined by an integer value supplied to the factory function (requires that all classes have a common base).

For example:

```
class Base_process
{
public:
    virtual ~Base_process() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class TwoJ : public Base_process
{
public:
    void do_something() {}
}
class ThreeJ : public Base_process
{
public:
    void do_something() {}
}

std::unique_ptr<Base_process> make_process(int a_type)
{
    if (a_type == 1) return std::unique_ptr<Base_process>(new TwoJ());
    if (a_type == 2) return std::unique_ptr<Base_process>(new ThreeJ());

    // Report invalid type or return an acceptable default if one exists.
    throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown type:" + std::to_string(a_type));
}
```

Comment: So my base class doesnt actually need to do anything neccessarily it just needs to be something from which all of the actual classes can be got at?

Comment: @JackMedley, yes. It defines an interface that all dervied classes must implement.

Comment: Ok I've build that and it seems to be ok with it! Great!
One other related thing is: How do I access methods in the derived classes now?

Comment: @JackMedley, the interface should declare all functions that the dervied classes implement. The client code should be written to use the interface, not a specific implementation of the interface,

Comment: Ahh that would be the purpose of the 'virtual' tag!  Ok I'll give that a shot.  Thanks again

Comment: Does a similar thing apply for class member variables? Or are they accesed without the needed for virtual declaration?

Comment: **Possible refinement:** Since the argument to `make_process()` is `int _atype`, I'd prefer to use `switch (a_type) { case n: }` rather than `if (a_type == n) {}`.

Comment: @DavidRR, yes a `switch` would also be fine, or a table that maps an `int` to some creation function.

Answer (score 2):

A factory method of sorts

```
std::unique_ptr<ProcessType> CreateProcess(int input){ 
    if(input == 2) return std::unique_ptr<ProcessType>(new TwoJ());
    .....
}
```

This assumes, of course, that the various classes you use have a common base class, here `ProcessType`, and that you are satisfied with interacting with it via a base class pointer.

Comment: `ProcessType` should be returned by pointer (or better yet smart pointer) not by value otherwise you'll slice the object.

Answer (score 0):

you can but, you need 1 base class for those all e.g.

```
Base* process;

if (input == 2) process = new TwoJ();
if (input == 3) process = new ThreeJ();
```

then to access those class all you need is:

```
if (input == 2) (TwoJ*)process->someTwoJMethod();
```

or by using dynamic_cast:

```
TwoJ* p = dynamic_cast<TwoJ*>(process);
if(p != 0) {
   p->someTwoJMethod();
}
```

with this you own responsibility to delete your object once it's go out of scope.
The previous answers are the best way in cpp using `std::unique_ptr` the object will get deleted automatically when the object go out of scope.