# Deletion entries static map of vector pointers c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a static map of vector pointers:

```
static std::map<type, std::vector<object *> > m_objects;
```

How should I delete the entries in this case?

Comment: Why vector of raw pointers? Why not use a vector of smart pointers instead, so they will be deleted automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `m_objects` owns the `object`s pointed to by the `std::vector` then `delete` must be called on each `object` in the `std::vector`, or use a smart pointer that will automatically delete the `object`s when the `std::vector` is destructed (in this case when it is removed from the `map`):

```
static std::map<type, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>>> m_objects;
```

If the `object`s are not owned by `m_object`s then `delete` must not be called (as they are used elsewhere).

---

See [What C++ Smart Pointer Implementations are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each entry in the map, and for each entry, iterate over each entry in the vector and delete them.

```
for (auto it : m_objects) {
    for (auto ptr : it.second) {
      delete ptr;
    }
}
```

A better solution might be to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be [not to use a vector of raw pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and take advantage of C++11 perfect forwarding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct object {
};

enum type {
    TYPE0,
    TYPE1
};

typedef std::map<type, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object> > > long_type;
static long_type m_objects;

int main() {

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<object>(new object))); // make_unique in C++14

    m_objects.insert(std::pair<type, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>>>(TYPE0, std::move(vec)));

    long_type::iterator it = m_objects.find(TYPE0);

    m_objects.erase(it);

    cout << m_objects.size(); // 0

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/5L4g1x

This way you don't have to worry about calling `delete` on each of your allocated objects (the map will not do it by itself).

As of inserting and deleting elements, the same stands for a normal `std::map` with [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase).